# How to select expanded or extended font styles in CSS for cross browser compatibility?

Tags: html, css, webfonts, typography

I'm currently building a webpage using a font that comes with a set of Expanded and Extended subfamilies:

http://www.gt-america.com/

What is the correct procedure to use these subfamilies via CSS so that they are displayed on Chrome and Safari? Using:

```
h1 {
font-family: 'GT America'
font-stretch: expanded;
```

}

is, to the best of my knowledge, not supported outside of Firefox and IE.

Comment: The font isn't GT America. It's GT America Extended or Expanded. The subfamilies are their own fonts.

Comment: This would be correct if those would be separate font families that can be selected using the font-family attribute. GT America has those subfamilies nested as styles within the GT America font. Targeting them via font-family as 'GT America Expanded' or 'GT America Extended' results in the font not being able to be displayed as these font families do technically not exist.

Comment: How are the font files setup? Looking at the font's website, those all appear as completely separate font families.

Comment: "How are the font files setup?"
- This is already answered in my previous comment.

Comment: Fair enough...but the website still appears to show the fonts as separate families and subfamilies. Have you tried reaching out to the font developer?